# Duda creando la interface para consumir de apis con Retrofit cuando no lleva el @PATH

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Como bien dice el título de la duda, estoy tratando de mostrar una lista de países con la siguiente URL dada por el profesor https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/all , para ello he creado una interface de la siguiente forma:

```
public interface ICountryService {

    String ENDPOINT = "https://restcountries.eu";


    @GET("/rest/v1/all")
    Call<List<Country>> getCountry(@Path("country") String country);


}
```

El caso es que no me deja quitar el @PATH porque da error pero intuyo que no debe llevarlo, pues la lista de países está en esa URL.

Comment: ¿Qué quieres obtener al hacer este pedido @GET("/rest/v1/all")
    Call<List<Country>> getCountry(@Path("country") String country); ??

Comment: Aca http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36232/app-android-con-retrofit-consumiendo-de-api-no-muestra-la-lista ya tenias la solución

Comment: Se utiliza @Path cuando requieres ingresar un valor para filtrar si es que tu API te la proporciona, como por ejemplo: endpoint/{Country}/another

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo ideal sería que separaras la url en trozos, puedes crear una nueva clase, algo así (escribo el código sin editor,de cabeza, puede haber algún fallo )

```
public class Constans{

public static final String URL ="https://restcountries.eu";
public static final String SERVICE_TYPE ="/rest";
public static final String API_VERSION = "/v1";
public static final String BASE_URL = URL+SERVICE_TYPE+API_VERSION;
}
```

Cuando instancias retrofit puedes hacer algo así:

```
 Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constans.BASE_URL) //todos los demás parametros
```

y luego

```
@GET("/all")
    Call<List<Country>> getCountry();
```