# App Android con Retrofit consumiendo de api no muestra la lista

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit

Pues eso el caso es que solo quiero mostrar el nombre de los países en una lista, pero no sé cómo obtener solo el nombre:

Esta es la clase principal:

```
 listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);


        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(ICountryService.ENDPOINT)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new GsonBuilder().create()))
                .build();

        ICountryService service = retrofit.create(ICountryService.class);

        Call<List<Country>> call = service.getCountry();


        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Country>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<List<Country>> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                if (response.isSuccess()) {
                    List<Country> countryList = response.body();
                    ArrayAdapter<Country> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, countryList);
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error: " + response.code(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error: " + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });
    }
```

La interface:

```
public interface ICountryService {

    String ENDPOINT = "https://restcountries.eu";


    @GET("/rest/v1/all")
    Call<List<Country>> getCountry();

}
```

La clase Country es muy extensa pero de toda la clase solo quiero mostrar la lista de países. ¿Cómo lo hago?:

```
public class Country {

    /**
     * 
     * (Required)
     * 
     */
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
```

Por supuesto, esta clase tiene generados los getter y setters

Método onResponse(dejo aquí esta implementación dada ya en la solución pero más adaptada al ejercicio):

```
 call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Country>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<List<Country>> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                if (response.isSuccess()) {
                    List<Country> countryList = response.body();
                    List<String> listaNombres = new ArrayList<String>();

                    for (Country c : countryList
                            ) {
                        listaNombres.add(c.getName());


                        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listaNombres);
                        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error: " + response.code(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error: " + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        });
```

Comment: Prueba con este código: http://pastebin.com/iBrBzhV2

Comment: Lo he generado a travez de http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: Muchas gracias por el código, ya está todo casi perfecto, ahora me muestra todos los países en la lista incluyendo la información de cada uno, el problema es que sólo quiero una lista de países.

Comment: haz un foreach de la lista y utiliza el método getName();

Comment: prueba con mi solución

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilizando la información obtenida desde https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/all y utilizando la página http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ para obtener la siguiente clase

```
-----------------------------------com.example.Country.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class Country {

@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("topLevelDomain")
@Expose
private List<String> topLevelDomain = new ArrayList<String>();
@SerializedName("alpha2Code")
@Expose
private String alpha2Code;
@SerializedName("alpha3Code")
@Expose
private String alpha3Code;
@SerializedName("callingCodes")
@Expose
private List<String> callingCodes = new ArrayList<String>();
@SerializedName("capital")
@Expose
private String capital;
@SerializedName("altSpellings")
@Expose
private List<String> altSpellings = new ArrayList<String>();
@SerializedName("relevance")
@Expose
private String relevance;
@SerializedName("region")
@Expose
private String region;
@SerializedName("subregion")
@Expose
private String subregion;
@SerializedName("translations")
@Expose
private Translations translations;
@SerializedName("population")
@Expose
private Integer population;
@SerializedName("latlng")
@Expose
private List<Double> latlng = new ArrayList<Double>();
@SerializedName("demonym")
@Expose
private String demonym;
@SerializedName("area")
@Expose
private Double area;
@SerializedName("gini")
@Expose
private Object gini;
@SerializedName("timezones")
@Expose
private List<String> timezones = new ArrayList<String>();
@SerializedName("borders")
@Expose
private List<Object> borders = new ArrayList<Object>();
@SerializedName("nativeName")
@Expose
private String nativeName;
@SerializedName("numericCode")
@Expose
private String numericCode;
@SerializedName("currencies")
@Expose
private List<String> currencies = new ArrayList<String>();
@SerializedName("languages")
@Expose
private List<String> languages = new ArrayList<String>();

/**
* 
* @return
* The name
*/
public String getName() {
return name;
}

/**
* 
* @param name
* The name
*/
public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The topLevelDomain
*/
public List<String> getTopLevelDomain() {
return topLevelDomain;
}

/**
* 
* @param topLevelDomain
* The topLevelDomain
*/
public void setTopLevelDomain(List<String> topLevelDomain) {
this.topLevelDomain = topLevelDomain;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The alpha2Code
*/
public String getAlpha2Code() {
return alpha2Code;
}

/**
* 
* @param alpha2Code
* The alpha2Code
*/
public void setAlpha2Code(String alpha2Code) {
this.alpha2Code = alpha2Code;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The alpha3Code
*/
public String getAlpha3Code() {
return alpha3Code;
}

/**
* 
* @param alpha3Code
* The alpha3Code
*/
public void setAlpha3Code(String alpha3Code) {
this.alpha3Code = alpha3Code;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The callingCodes
*/
public List<String> getCallingCodes() {
return callingCodes;
}

/**
* 
* @param callingCodes
* The callingCodes
*/
public void setCallingCodes(List<String> callingCodes) {
this.callingCodes = callingCodes;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The capital
*/
public String getCapital() {
return capital;
}

/**
* 
* @param capital
* The capital
*/
public void setCapital(String capital) {
this.capital = capital;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The altSpellings
*/
public List<String> getAltSpellings() {
return altSpellings;
}

/**
* 
* @param altSpellings
* The altSpellings
*/
public void setAltSpellings(List<String> altSpellings) {
this.altSpellings = altSpellings;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The relevance
*/
public String getRelevance() {
return relevance;
}

/**
* 
* @param relevance
* The relevance
*/
public void setRelevance(String relevance) {
this.relevance = relevance;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The region
*/
public String getRegion() {
return region;
}

/**
* 
* @param region
* The region
*/
public void setRegion(String region) {
this.region = region;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The subregion
*/
public String getSubregion() {
return subregion;
}

/**
* 
* @param subregion
* The subregion
*/
public void setSubregion(String subregion) {
this.subregion = subregion;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The translations
*/
public Translations getTranslations() {
return translations;
}

/**
* 
* @param translations
* The translations
*/
public void setTranslations(Translations translations) {
this.translations = translations;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The population
*/
public Integer getPopulation() {
return population;
}

/**
* 
* @param population
* The population
*/
public void setPopulation(Integer population) {
this.population = population;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The latlng
*/
public List<Double> getLatlng() {
return latlng;
}

/**
* 
* @param latlng
* The latlng
*/
public void setLatlng(List<Double> latlng) {
this.latlng = latlng;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The demonym
*/
public String getDemonym() {
return demonym;
}

/**
* 
* @param demonym
* The demonym
*/
public void setDemonym(String demonym) {
this.demonym = demonym;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The area
*/
public Double getArea() {
return area;
}

/**
* 
* @param area
* The area
*/
public void setArea(Double area) {
this.area = area;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The gini
*/
public Object getGini() {
return gini;
}

/**
* 
* @param gini
* The gini
*/
public void setGini(Object gini) {
this.gini = gini;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The timezones
*/
public List<String> getTimezones() {
return timezones;
}

/**
* 
* @param timezones
* The timezones
*/
public void setTimezones(List<String> timezones) {
this.timezones = timezones;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The borders
*/
public List<Object> getBorders() {
return borders;
}

/**
* 
* @param borders
* The borders
*/
public void setBorders(List<Object> borders) {
this.borders = borders;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The nativeName
*/
public String getNativeName() {
return nativeName;
}

/**
* 
* @param nativeName
* The nativeName
*/
public void setNativeName(String nativeName) {
this.nativeName = nativeName;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The numericCode
*/
public String getNumericCode() {
return numericCode;
}

/**
* 
* @param numericCode
* The numericCode
*/
public void setNumericCode(String numericCode) {
this.numericCode = numericCode;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The currencies
*/
public List<String> getCurrencies() {
return currencies;
}

/**
* 
* @param currencies
* The currencies
*/
public void setCurrencies(List<String> currencies) {
this.currencies = currencies;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The languages
*/
public List<String> getLanguages() {
return languages;
}

/**
* 
* @param languages
* The languages
*/
public void setLanguages(List<String> languages) {
this.languages = languages;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Translations.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class Translations {

@SerializedName("de")
@Expose
private String de;
@SerializedName("es")
@Expose
private String es;
@SerializedName("fr")
@Expose
private String fr;
@SerializedName("ja")
@Expose
private String ja;
@SerializedName("it")
@Expose
private String it;

/**
* 
* @return
* The de
*/
public String getDe() {
return de;
}

/**
* 
* @param de
* The de
*/
public void setDe(String de) {
this.de = de;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The es
*/
public String getEs() {
return es;
}

/**
* 
* @param es
* The es
*/
public void setEs(String es) {
this.es = es;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The fr
*/
public String getFr() {
return fr;
}

/**
* 
* @param fr
* The fr
*/
public void setFr(String fr) {
this.fr = fr;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The ja
*/
public String getJa() {
return ja;
}

/**
* 
* @param ja
* The ja
*/
public void setJa(String ja) {
this.ja = ja;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The it
*/
public String getIt() {
return it;
}

/**
* 
* @param it
* The it
*/
public void setIt(String it) {
this.it = it;
}

}
```

En el vista principal:

```
List<Country> countryList = response.body();
List<String> nameList;
foreach(Country country: countryList){
nameList.add(country.getName());
}
```

Comment: Creo que tu solución es la correcta pero no sé de qué manera ponerlo para que funcione, así lo tengo y seguro que no es así.

`List<Country> countryList = response.body();
                    List<String> listaNombres=null;
                    for (Country c: countryList) {
                        listaNombres.add(c.getName());
                    }
                    ArrayAdapter<Country> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, countryList);
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: lo pongo arriba para que se vea más claro

Comment: @Jose debes usar un foreach, no un for

Comment: @Jose si mi solución es la correcta marcala por favor

Comment: Muchas gracias, la verdad es que no sé por qué android estudio me pone un for cuando escribo un foreach...

Comment: Resulta que Android te escribe un for aunque sea un foreach, el problema está en que me he equivocado pasando un Country en vez de un String, como tu bien has puesto.